# load photo from device in iOS4

Tags: iphone, uiimage, ios4, photo

i want to load count of `UIImages` from `PhotoAlbum` at a time and display on the UIView.
in iOS3 ,it may like :

```
NSString *file_path = @"/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/" 
NSArray *imageSource = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:file_path error:nil] ; 

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageSource objectAtIndex:index]] ;
if (!image) {
NSLog(@"load image fail : %@" ,[imageSource objectAtIndex:index]) ;
}
return image ;
```

and in iOS3, this method is work !
but now in iOS4 , i know the path have been changed to

```
@"/var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/100APPLE/"
```

and imageSource can parse to 2 types file : .BTH(full size) .THM(thumbnail) ,but it **can't**
read **BTH** from `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:XXX.BTH]`

is there any solution for this problem ?  or this method should be reject from Apple ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're allowed to go into the filesystem to get photos, your app will be rejected outright. You should try something like this:

```
-(IBAction)openAlbums {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        UIImagePickerController *UIPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        UIPicker.allowsImageEditing = NO;
        UIPicker.delegate = self;
        UIPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:UIPicker animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Error" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

Of course, this won't be the EXACT code *you* in particular will want to use, so just modify it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found no better way to display whole images in my own Controller.
I adjust the flow to fit my requirement.

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage: (UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{

 // Transform image to NSData
 NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

 // Create your path with Customized file-name   
 NSString *paths=NSHomeDirectory();   
 NSString *filename=@"XXXX.png";
 NSString *save=[paths stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];   

 [imageData writeToFile:save atomically:NO];   

 [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

The method occur when user clicked the thumbnil. if you want to perform multi-select, my solution is to use **NSOperation** to deal with file save and it still need user clicked the thumbnil.
by the way, it may need to **scale** the photo image after UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) ,the Original image(1200x1600) almost 300Kb

Answer (score 0):

use these two method for load your photo form device.

```
-(void)takePhoto:(id)sender
 {
  UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

  //Use camera if device has one otherwise use photo library
  if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
   {
     [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
   }
  else
  {
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
   }

   [imagePicker setDelegate:self];

   //Show image picker
   [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
   //Modal so we wait for it to complete
   [imagePicker release];
     }

  //********** RECEIVE PICTURE **********
  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
  { 
  //Get image
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

  //Display in ImageView object (if you want to display it
    [playerImage setImage:image];

  //Take image picker off the screen (required)
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
```